# How to center list elements from two lists as though all individual elements?

Tags: html, css

Q: I need to centre the list-item elements of two unordered lists as though they were the children of just one list:

```
Example:
                {[1][1][1][1][2][2]}
                {      [2][2]      }
```

**HTML Layout**

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>2</li>
    </ul>
<div>
```

**What I've tried**

1. Floating the `<li>` elements left comes close to this and we can play with the width of the `<div>` container element but of course everything is then left-aligned.
2. Setting `display: inline` on the `<li>` items and `text-align: center` on the containing `div` which also comes close but ultimately not what I need.

Comment: Why is 2 not what you need. In what way?

Comment: @JamieBarker probably because OP did not reset the `ul`

Comment: A little unclear on what you mean by reset the `ul`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set everything to `display: inline`

http://jsfiddle.net/p5oax2u9/1/

```
div {
    text-align: center;
    width: 60px;
}

ul, li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I made the width on the `div` 60px so it is easier to see the result

Answer (score 1):

Better to use `display: inline;` &   `padding: 0;` for ul and li in your css file. This will give you your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

By centering the div + text-align: centered and display the list elements inline should work.

```
li {
    display: inline;
}
div {
    text-align: center;
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ABr/dsL5sfLy/

Answer (score 0):

This can be a flexibile way to do rows of list items.

You can also use pseudo first-of-type last-of-type if you wish to hide specific items.

```css
#Wrap {
  width: 500px;
}
#ul1,
#ul2 {
  list-style: none;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
li {
  float: left;
  width: 25%; 
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:5px;
  text-align:center;
}
#ul1 li {
  background: #def;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
#ul2 li {
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div id="Wrap">
  <ul id="ul1">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="ul1">
    <li></li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <div>
```